# hide first flexbox item when new item added

Tags: css, flexbox

I've got a challenge. I've got a flexbox with three items:

[image]

I'd like for the red item to disappear when a fourth item is added:

[image]

When black is removed I want red back. The key is that I want this to be pure CSS, no JS. When I set a height, then hide overflow and flex-wrap:wrap the black box wraps and disappears, and wrap-reverse does the same thing. Here's what I've got so far:

```
<div class=container>
  <div class=red></div>
  <div class=green></div>
  <div class=blue></div>
  <div class=black></div>
</div>

<style>
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.container > div {
  height: 200px;
  width:33%;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

</style>
```

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/utnuc/pen/NWgrqmd) to play around with. I realize I could set the order of red to 4 dynamically `$('.red').css('order','4');` and it would work, but I'm looking for pure css. Also willing to entertain a non-flex option that is responsive. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you can probably create something using "quantity queries", as explained here, https://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css/ Not sure why this would need to work without any JS to begin with though - what dynamically adds/removes the last item then to begin with?

Comment: I’m trying to work with an existing LMS that is a single page app style quiz player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to @Paulide_D's answer, you can use `:not(:nth-last-child(-n+3))` selector, this supports unlimited additions.

```js
$('.additem').click(function() {
  $('.container').append('<div class=black></div>');
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* commented to see where black goes */
  /*overflow:hidden;*/
}

.container>div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 33%;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.container div:not(:nth-last-child(-n+3)) {
  display: none;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=container>
  <div class=red></div>
  <div class=green></div>
  <div class=blue></div>
</div>

<button class=additem>ADD</button>
```

Comment: this is brilliant, I'd never considered `div:not(:nth-last-child...`

Answer (score 2):

If there are only ever going to be a maximum of 4 items you can make the first one `display:none` with the selector `.container div:nth-last-child(4)`

```js
$('.additem').click(function() {
  $('.container').append('<div class=black></div>');
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* commented to see where black goes */
  /*overflow:hidden;*/
}

.container>div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 33%;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.container div:nth-last-child(4) {
  display: none;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=container>
  <div class=red></div>
  <div class=green></div>
  <div class=blue></div>
</div>

<button class=additem>ADD</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I cannot guarantee max only 4 items.

Comment: Then JS would be the method, as you add a div, hide the first unhidden div. Using classes would make this simpler